# Facebook login promblem in my app

Tags: android

Here is the stacktrace:

```
08-04 11:14:20.035 31839-31839/datinglove.co.in E/Zygote: Zygote:  error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:198
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add more description about your problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Answer (score 0):

Once check internet Permission with app.
Have you used any third part library in app ?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Comment: so got your issue ?